# Get File Object used by a CSV Reader/Writer Object

Tags: python, csv

Is there any way to access the file object used by a CSV writer/reader object after it has been instantiated?  I openned up the csv module, and it appears it's contest are builtin.  I also tried setting the file object as a property but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'fileobj'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`csv.writer` is a "builtin" function.  That is, it is written in compiled C code rather than Python.  So its internal variables can't be accessed from Python code.

That being said, I'm not sure **why** you would need to inspect the csv.writer object to find out the file object.  That object is specified when creating the object:

```
w = csv.writer(fileobj, dialect, ...)
```

So if you need to access that object later, just save it in another variable.

Comment: I'm not creating the writer, a factory function is creating the csv.writer object so I never actually have a reference to the file object.

Comment: What is that factory function?  Is it written in Python?  Can you inspect its code to figure out how to get the file object?

Comment: There are plenty of good reasons why you might want to do this. Maybe you want to close the underlying file and you aren't in the function scope where you created it. Sure, you could stash a reference to the underlying file, but how clean is that? Not as clean as if the csv object provided a reference to its file object.

Comment: I agree. It'd be better if the CSV reader/writer objects actually provided references to the `file`-like objects they're using … but the current standard library doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, there is no straightforward way to get the file object back out once you put it into a csv object.  My approach would probably be to subclass the csv writer and readers you're using so they can carry that data around with them.  Of course, this assumes the ability to be able to directly access the types of classes the factory function makes (among other things).